# How far in advance can I pass security and enter the airside in Schiphol?

Tags: airports, sleeping, ams

I have a very early flight in Schiphol.  Since I don't have any other way to arrive there in the morning I will have to go the previous day.

Although I will be arriving quite late, it would be nice to enter as soon as possible to get a bit of rest before the plane.

**How far in advance can one pass security and enter airside?**

Comment: I have noticed that it is more checking in and luggage drop that keeps people from crossing security early, but I have never tried to do it on a different date. (I usually cross into the secure area about 4 to 3 hours before my flight.)

Answer (score 3):

My flight was departing at 6h00 in the morning and I was able to enter the terminal just around 23h45 from the previous day. I did the online check-in.

I am not sure if this is an airport policy or if this can be negotiated per company basis though.